# Flow on Task to trigger validation rule

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule, tasks

I have a validation rule on the Task object which simply points to a checkbox field, if true then error.

I am using a fast field update flow with some simple logic that, according to the debugger, runs as expected. However, although the final node of the flow appears to set the validation checkbox true the records are being created without error.

I have tested the validation rule in isolation and it works as intended when manually setting the field true.

I am using the same record in the flow debugger as I am using in my testing via the UI

I have a different flow for a different use-case that is very similar and is working properly using the same basic framework (if combination of x/y/z fields exists on same parent, then assign checkbox field true which triggers a validation rule)

Any idea what may be happening?

[image: Flow debugger path]
[image: Debugger setting checkbox value]
[image: Validation Rule]

Comment: It *sounds* like this should work, at least according to what you've said and the [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) documentation. I'd guess there's some other issue that means this isn't being processed the way you expected. Is the correct version of the flow active, for example?

Comment: Sadly yes, I confirmed everything necessary is active. There is one trigger on the Task object which is part of a managed package and therefore not visible to me, but I have no reason to believe it should interfere apart from this one issue.

Comment: I'd also look at FLS as the running user may not have access to a field value (and hence it is NULL) - affecting your logic path(s)

Comment: A good thought I hadn't checked yet however FLS is not an issue.